# can spring webflow handle a dynamic expression inside "evaluate" tag?

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I see that in spring webflow you can use dynamic expression for the view

```
<view-state id="error" view="error-#{externalContext.locale}.xhtml" />
```

Can I do the same for evaluate ? Something like:

```
 <evaluate expression="#{variable}Controller.processData()" />
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question: No, that's not possible. According to the xsd of spring webflow:

```
<xsd:attribute name="expression" type="expression" use="required">
```

where

```
<xsd:simpleType name="expression">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="template">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

According to the documentation the expression should have been of type "template" so that it is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea:

```
<evaluate expression="webFlowUtil.getBean(variable.concat('Controller'))" result="flowScope.controller"/>
```

with

```
@Component
public class WebFlowUtil {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public Object getBean(String beanName) {
        return applicationContext.getBean(beanName);
    }
}
```

then later use

```
<evaluate expression="controller.processData()" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I see it as a nice workaround but still the answer is "no, the values inside expression will not be evaluated"